# Should I include test scores and recommender information given elsewhere in my application in my CV for graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

All of the universities I am applying to require a CV as part of the application process.

As I am requesting the recommender from the on-line application and also giving the test scores there, is it necessary to add these in the CV?

Comment: The question of photo in CV is addressed [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/in-what-situations-would-it-be-appropriate-to-include-ones-photograph-in-a-cv), so I'm going to edit that part out of your post and narrow it so it isn't so broad. Refer to the question I've just linked for answers to that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean references? Occasionally you will see a CV that lists references or it will say "References available on request." I myself have always just left them off.

As far as test scores go, it is typical to leave off them off since you have to send the official scores separately anyway.

Comment: FYI I've removed the part about photo from the question, since that's addressed at length in [another question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/in-what-situations-would-it-be-appropriate-to-include-ones-photograph-in-a-cv), and to narrow it so it isn't so broad.

Comment: @ff524 I edited that part out then. I vaguely remember a previous question about test scores on your CV so I am searching for that as well...