# Inclusion of a Personal Photo in Academic CVs: Appropriate or Not?

Tags: application, etiquette, cv, academic-life, professionalism

I'm in the process of refining my curriculum vitae (CV) for academic purposes, and I'm contemplating whether to include a personal photograph. This decision seems to vary greatly across different cultures and industries, and I am unsure about the norm within academic circles.

Is including a personal photo in an academic CV generally considered appropriate or advantageous? I am concerned about potential positive or negative biases that might arise from including my picture. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding if the inclusion of a photo is perceived differently in various academic fields or geographical locations.

Comment: related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98364/photo-requirement-on-cv